# How to remove duplicate objects from java script array?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have two arrays as shown below. I want to remove Array2 elements from Array1. How do I do that?(either in plain java script or using ExtJS)

```
var Array1 = [];

var Array2 = [];

Array1.push(['eth0'], ['eth1']);

Array2.push(['eth1']);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference ?

Comment: Do you want to remove the values completely, or just the duplicate values?

Comment: @Michael Dillon Its not exact duplicate. Maybe ExtJS has some synonym to [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)'s `_.uniq()` ?

Comment: Are you sure you want an array of arrays, not of strings?  `Array1` looks like `[['eth0'], ['eth1']]`.  You sure you want that, compared to `['eth0', 'eth1']`?

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeDupes(a1, a2) {
  var index = {}, result = [], i, l;
  for (i=0, l=a2.length; i<l; i++) {
    index['-' + a2[i]] = "";
  }
  for (i=0, l=a1.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (index['-' + a1[i]] !== "") result.push(a1[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

- The `index` object is for speedy look-up of values so we can test their existence quickly.
- The `'-' +` is to migrate the fact that values could be things like `toString` that also exist as object properties. When prefixed with a letter that regular JavaScript identifiers cannot start with, every value will be safe for use as an object key.

Example:

```
removeDupes([1,2,3,4], [2,4,5]);
// -> [1,3]

removeDupes([2,4,5], [1,2,3,4]);
// -> [5]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the array filter function available to you, you can do something like the following:

```
var filteredArr = Array1.filter(function(val){
    return Array2.indexOf(val) != -1;
})
```

I think this will only be supported in newer browsers, though. It's an elegant way to handle the situation, so you may want to take a look at a library like [UnderscoreJS](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter) which will include filtering, defaulting to the native implementation if available.

If using UnderscoreJS, the code would look very similar:

```
var filterdArr = _.filter(Array1, function(val) {return Array2.indexOf(val) != -1});
```

Comment: This won't work as the arrays of arrays not of strings (assuming that's what he really wants)

Comment: You're absolutely right - didn't read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://www.developersnippets.com/2008/10/30/remove-duplicates-from-array-using-javascript/. Concat your arrays with concat() and call uniqueArr().

Comment: That link you provided gives a solution to remove duplicates from just one array, and not two as asked.